# Inject async dependency in inversify

Tags: javascript, typescript, inversion-of-control

My question is very close to [How to inject an asynchronous dependency in inversify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40880447/how-to-inject-an-asynchronous-dependency-in-inversify)

But, In the answer, I saw that some new feature was added in version 3. Now we have version 5. How to make this stuff with DB in version 5? Simply I need to run some async method before injecting DB. 
Like this:

```
@injectable()
export class ApplicationDbContext {

    public db!: Db;

    async build() {
        this.db = await MongoDbConnection.getConnection();
    }

}
```